# HTML Scraping with Beautiful Soup - Unwanted line breaks

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to write a script to get data from a html page and save it to .csv file. However I've run into 3 minor problems.

First of all, when saving to .csv I get some unwanted line breaks which mess up the output file.

Secondly, players' names (the data concerns NBA players) appear twice.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time


teams = ['atlanta-hawks', 'boston-celtics', 'brooklyn-nets']

seasons = []
a=2018
while (a>2016):
    seasons.append(str(a))
    a-=1
print(seasons)  
for season in seasons:

    for team in teams:
        my_url = ' https://www.spotrac.com/nba/'+team+'/cap/'+ season +'/'

        headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0"}

        response = requests.get(my_url)
        response.content

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

        stat_table = soup.find_all('table', class_ = 'datatable')


        my_table = stat_table[0]

        plik = team + season + '.csv'   
        with open (plik, 'w') as r:
            for row in my_table.find_all('tr'):
                for cell in row.find_all('th'):
                    r.write(cell.text)
                    r.write(";")

            for row in my_table.find_all('tr'):
                for cell in row.find_all('td'): 
                    r.write(cell.text)
                    r.write(";")
```

Also, some of the numbers that are seperated by "." are being automatically converted to dates.

Any ideas how I could solve those problems?

[Screenshot of output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myyTf.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richard provided a complete answer that works for the 3.6 + versions.
It executes `file.write()` for every cell, though, which is not necessary, so here's an alternative with str.format() which will work for python versions before 3.6, and writes once per row:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

teams = ['atlanta-hawks', 'boston-celtics', 'brooklyn-nets']
seasons = [2018, 2017]

for season in seasons:
    for team in teams:
        my_url = 'https://www.spotrac.com/nba/{}/cap/{}/'.format(team, season)
        headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

        response = requests.get(my_url)
        response.content

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        stat_table = soup.find_all('table', class_ = 'datatable')
        my_table = stat_table[0]

        csv_file = '{}-{}.csv'.format(team, season)
        with open(csv_file, 'w') as r:
            for row in my_table.find_all('tr'):
                row_string = ''

                for cell in row.find_all('th'):
                    row_string='{}{};'.format(row_string, cell.text.strip())

                for i, cell in enumerate(row.find_all('td')):
                    cell_string = cell.a.text if i==0 else cell.text
                    row_string='{}{};'.format(row_string, cell_string)

                r.write("{}\n".format(row_string))
```

Comment: Ah, yeah. Good call. It makes sense to only write to the file once per line.

Answer (score 2):

I made a few changes to your script. To build the URLs, I'm using string interpolation (instead of concatenation). To get rid of the extra whitespace, I'm using the `strip()` method that is defined on strings. When it comes to the duplication of names, I selected the `<a>` tag, then called `.text` on the BeautifulSoup selector.

```
# pip install beautifulsoup4
# pip install requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

teams = ['atlanta-hawks', 'boston-celtics', 'brooklyn-nets']
seasons = [2018, 2017]

for season in seasons:
    for team in teams:
        my_url = f'https://www.spotrac.com/nba/{team}/cap/{season}/'
        headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

        response = requests.get(my_url)
        response.content

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
        stat_table = soup.find_all('table', class_ = 'datatable')
        my_table = stat_table[0]

        csv_file = f'{team}-{season}.csv'
        with open(csv_file, 'w') as r:
            for row in my_table.find_all('tr'):
                for cell in row.find_all('th'):
                    r.write(cell.text.strip())
                    r.write(";")

                for i, cell in enumerate(row.find_all('td')):
                    if i == 0:
                        r.write(cell.a.text.strip())
                    else:
                        r.write(cell.text.strip())
                    r.write(";")
                r.write("\n")
```

When it comes to Excel converting numbers like `1.31` to dates, that's Excel trying to be smart, and failing. I think when you go to import a CSV, you can choose what column types to use for the data. Check out [this guide](https://help.aftership.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008353147-How-to-correctly-import-open-a-CSV-file-in-Excel-).